# Why can't int.TryParse parse number grouping (but double.TryParse can)?

Tags: c#, numbers, format, locale

In C#, why can't int.TryParse parse number grouping (but double.TryParse can)?

```
        int i1 = 13579;
        string si1 = i1.ToString("N0");  //becomes 13,579
        int i2 = 0;
        bool result1 = int.TryParse(si1, out i2); //gets false and 0

        double d1 = 24680.0;
        string sd1 = d1.ToString("N0"); //becomes 24,680
        double d2 = 0;
        bool result2 = double.TryParse(sd1, out d2); //gets true and 24680.0
```

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the conversion factor of both data type is different. parameter assigned in string value will be different from both data type.

in Int.TryParse does not contains **culture specific thousand separator** parameter in form of conversion parameter

for example

in Int.TryParse the form of parameter is

```
[ws][sign]digits[ws]

ws: White space (optional)
sign: An optional Sign (+-)
digit: sequance of digit (0-9)
```

and in Decimal.TryParse the form of parameter is

```
[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]

ws: White space (optional)
sign: An optional Sign (+-)
digit: sequance of digit (0-9)
,: culture specific thousand separator
.: culture specific decimal point.
fractional-digits: fractional digit after decimal point.
```

You can get more information from msdn. [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the allowed `NumberStyles`, which is taken into account when parsing the string back into a number.

> Determines the styles permitted in numeric string arguments that are passed to the Parse and TryParse methods of the integral and floating-point numeric types.

This returns `true` and stores the expected number in `i2`:

```
bool result1 = int.TryParse(si1,
   NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out i2);
```

You may also want to take a look at the other `NumberStyles` options. For example, `NumberStyles.Number` allows thousands as well as decimal points, white space, etc.

---

The default value for `int.TryParse` (if none is specified) is `NumberStyles.Integer`, which allows only a leading sign, and leading and trailing white space.

The default for `double.TryParse` is `NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands`, which allows leading sign and white space, but also thousands, exponents and decimal points.